# Problem writing a function (pl/pgsql) to determine a degree of similarity

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have a schema made of 5 tables. I think 2 of them are useful to solve my problem :
- **polling_station**, made of the number of **expressed votes** and many other columns related to votes
- **department**, which has an ID and a name
3 others :
- candidate
- voice
- municipality
I need to create a **function** that determines the **degree of similarity** between **each department** based on the "**expressed votes**".
I have no idea how to do it right now, if you could give me a hand, that would be great!
I have just been told that to calculate the similarity, I should use the cosine one :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

(EDIT)
A row of this database would be :
Candidate(id : 4, lastname : HAMON, firstname : Benoît, sex : M)
Polling_station(id : 0001, id_district : 03, ps_name : Mairie, coords : "43.755611, 4.013062", address : null, zipcode : 34160, city : "Saint-Hilaire-de-Beauvoir", registered : 302, voters : 270, abstentions : 32, expressed : 263, nil : 2, blank : 5)
Municipality(id : 263, m_name : "Saint-Hilaire-de-Beauvoir)
Department(id : 34, d_name : "Hérault)
Voice(nb_voices)

If you want the whole data (but it is in French) :
https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/election-presidentielle-2017-resultats-par-bureaux-de-vote-tour-1/table/?disjunctive.libelle_de_la_commune

Thank you in advance for your answer(s)!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so we know what *you* mean by "degree of similarity".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about finding a concept and not about programming.